# How to refer to a function?

Tags: php, hook, mediawiki

I am learning how to use [hooks](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks) in mediawiki. I am also new to PHP.
General hook handler can be added by putting next line in to LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgHooks['event'][] = 'function';
```

Suppose I wrote  `myfunction` in `my.php` file. How can I point to this function from LocalSettings.php

Edit. I have written some function in my.php file. How to refer to this function?
I should tell mediawiki where find this function.I don't know how to do it.
Should I write `'$wgHooks['event'][] = 'my.php:function'`. Or I should `include` my.php file to LocalSetting and then just write `'$wgHooks['event'][] = 'function'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks#Writing_an_event_handler) say, you need to push a string with your function name (or an array of strings etc.) to the hook array.

AFAIK, when triggering the hook they will be invoked with [`call_user_func()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php). So, it will depend on your function declaration in the my.php file. With a `myfunction`, it should be

```
$wgHooks['event'][] = 'myfunction';
```

Comment: should I `include` my.php file to LocalSettings.php?

Comment: Yes, see [Manual:Extensions#Installing an extension (step 3)](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aExtensions#Installing_an_extension).

Answer (score 2):

from what i read from the mediawiki docs, you need to create an extension, and in your extension you install your hook. in my.php you will write:

```
 // $wgHooks is a global variable
 $wgHooks['event'][] = 'function';
```

Hope i understand correctly
Extension docs
[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aExtensions)

Comment: but I don't want create an extention. I want just run function on some event (hook).

Comment: you need to include my.php in mediawiki in order to be able to install the event handler. the easy way to do it is to create a basic extension. the "hard" way (not that hard actually, but bad practice) is to modify the mediawiki source code, but that's what extensions are for: to be able to include your own source code without modifing the core.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand completely what you want, but if you want to call a user defined function you can use [call_user_func](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) which takes as argument the name of your function. You have to [include](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file so the function will be available.

```
call_user_func('myfunction ', array());
```

Answer (score 0):

You refer to functions via [callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) in PHP. A callback is one of these:

1. a function name: `'myFunc'`
2. an array containing a class name and a function name: `array('MyClass', 'myFunc')`
3. an array containing an object and a function name: `array($myObj, 'myFunc')`
4. an anonymous function (which is technically a [Closure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) object): `function($x, $y) { /* PHP code */ }` (this is PHP 5.3+ only, but so are recent versions of MediaWiki)

Invoking these callbacks via `call_user_func($callback, $arg1, $arg2)` will be equivalent to the following, respectively:

1. `myFunc($arg1, $arg2);`
2. `MyClass::myFunc($arg1, $arg2);`
3. `$myObj->myFunc($arg1, $arg2);`
4. executing the body of the anonymous function, replacing `$x` and `$y` with `$arg1` and `$arg2`

If this code would fail (e.g. you use the first version, and the function `myFunc` is not loaded), the callback will also fail. You can use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) with the second form, in MediaWiki that is normally done via [$wgAutoloadClasses](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgAutoloadClasses):

```
// in MyExtension.php
$wgHooks['event'][] = array('MyExtension', 'myEventHandler');
$wgAutoloadClasses['MyExtension'] = dirname(__FILE__) . 'MyExtension.body.php';

// in MyExtension.body.php
class MyExtension {
    public function myEventHandler($p1, $p2) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

That way, you can load `MyExtension.php` (which is a small file with configuration settings only) from `LocalSettings.php`, and `MyExtension.body.php` (which has all the code) only gets loaded in those requests which actually use your extension.